# How could I share common hook function for multiple flask servers

Tags: python, flask

Suppose I need to do  `before_request` for each flask servers

How can I share the following snippet to each servers without `COPY-PASTE`

```
    @app.before_request
    def before_request(*args, **kwargs):
        params = get_params()
        if params.has_key('start_dt') and params.has_key('end_dt'):
            g.mongo_query = Mongo.get_date_range_query(params)
        else:
            g.mongo_query = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

You could use [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) for this. If you initialize your flask applications like so:

```
from flask import Flask
import yourdb

def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)

    yourdb.init_app(app)

    #add_extensions
    #add_blueprints/views
    # ... some other configuration ...

    @app.before_request
    def before_request(*args, **kwargs):
        #Your code

    return app
```

From manage/run, you would then

```
    from somewhere import create_app
    app = create_app(<your_config>)
```